# Join two queries in MySQL to map result of one query with another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query like below in `MYSQL`. This query gives me list of table names without certain special charcters in the column names.

```
select distinct A.table_name from (select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' order by TABLE_NAME) A LEFT JOIN 
(select table_name from information_schema.columns where (COLUMN_NAME like '% %' or COLUMN_NAME like '%{%' or COLUMN_NAME like '%(%' or COLUMN_NAME like '%;%' 
or COLUMN_NAME like '%.%') and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' order by TABLE_NAME) B ON (A.TABLE_NAME=B.TABLE_NAME) where B.table_name IS NULL
```

Result of the above query:

```
100_test
101_test
102_backup
103_backup
```

I have another query like below:

```
select src_table,dst_table from test.mapping
```

Here `test` is database and `mapping` is the table name.

Result:

```
100_test    100_testing
101_test    101_testing
102_backup  102_backup_old
103_backup  103_backup_old
105_old_test    105_archived
```

Now I want to create a query that gives me src_table and dst_table from `test.mapping` for each table of the result of the `1st` query.

I want to join both queries as a single query which gives me result like below

```
100_test    100_testing
101_test    101_testing
102_backup  102_backup_old
103_backup  103_backup_old
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select src_table,dst_table from test.mapping
where src_table in 
(
select distinct A.table_name from (select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' order by TABLE_NAME) A LEFT JOIN 
(select table_name from information_schema.columns where (COLUMN_NAME like '% %' or COLUMN_NAME like '%{%' or COLUMN_NAME like '%(%' or COLUMN_NAME like '%;%' 
or COLUMN_NAME like '%.%') and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testing' order by TABLE_NAME) B ON (A.TABLE_NAME=B.TABLE_NAME) where B.table_name IS NULL 
)
```